# Get Google search result link attach to my website

Tags: search

I want to get Top 10 link that searched in google result and put the top 10 website link and its title to my website.
For example , i want to get " Computer Science " as my search query and i want to get the links that google return and put it to my website.

is there any way to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that with persistent effort it is possible to get on to page 1 of Google search results for almost any keyword, especially for local results. That being said, the reality is that getting page 1 search results for a broad keywords like "computer science" will be a Herculean task.

Organic search is very competitive and should not be undertaken lightly. All search engine optimization (SEO) requires extensive research, planning and effort to ensure that your site and content is, and remains, high quality, relevant, and compliant with the best practices of the search engine.

There are many resources to learn about SEO (just Google!) but a good place to start learning the basics is going to be the Google Search Engine Optimization Starter Guide: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf